# Regular expression for WKT Polygon

Tags: regex

What would be the regular expression for a [WKT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text_representation_of_geometry) polygon format as shown below.

POLYGON ((30.00 10.05, 40 40, 20.5 40, 10.8 20.3, 30 10))

Comment: are you also considering "POLYGON ((35 10, 45 45, 15 40, 10 20, 35 10),
(20 30, 35 35, 30 20, 20 30))" too?

Answer (score 2):

Below Regex will match WKT polygon pattern:

```
POLYGON [(]{2}(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)((,\s(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)))*[)]{2}
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/cILVYR/2

Answer (score 0):

Here is a regex pattern that also consideres cutouts. It also matches the start and end of the string. If that is not necessary remove the `^` & `$` from the start/end.

```
^POLYGON\s*[(]{2}\s*(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s*(\d+(?:\.\d+)?\s*)?(?:(?:\s*,\s*(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s*\1))*(?:(?:[)]{1}\s*,\s*[(]{1}(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s*(\d+(?:\.\d+)?\s*))?(?:(?:\s*,\s*(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s*(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)))*)*\s*[)]{2}$
```